# Resolving circular dependency in providers

Tags: angular

I have providers array as below

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            multi: true,
            useFactory: () => () => UploadService.setIsFlow(),
            deps: [UploadService]
        },
        {
            provide: 'FILE_HANDLER',
            multi: true,
            useFactory: () => {
                return UploadService.isFlow ? serviceOne : serviceTwo;
            },
            deps: [UploadService]
        }
    ]
```

So the APP_INITIALISER and 'FILE_HANDLER'depend on the UploadService. Hope this is the reason for circular dependency.
The setIsFlow method of UploadService sets the value of isFlow variable.

I am clueless on fixing this circular dependency issue. Can someone help

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: @Chellappanவ Here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4uf2f . Though i couldnt replicate the circular dependency, But the click of print value button not working

Comment: this is not working because: 

1. you use multi: true for your file handler provider, which leads to provide a list for FILE_HANDLER; but then you directly calls functions on the list
2. You provide classes in FILE_HANDLER factory, instead of instances

But there is no circular dependency error here, the issue is elsewhere